# Delphi disable form while loading

Tags: delphi, tform

In my application, I have a main form, with the ability to load some images in database.
While images is loading, I want to show a form, with the progress indicator (with bsNone border style).

But, if I show with form with ShowModal, execution of main form is stopped, so I can't to that.

If I call Show, user have access to all other form components, and it can be dangerous, while photo is not loaded completely.

I need to get the way, to disable everything on main form, while loading isn't completed.

Please, advice me, how it is possible.

Comment: If you' d like to keep a modal form, you could call the routine from your modal shown form. e.g. by handing over the method to call within the constructror of the modal shown form.

Comment: Apart from disabling the form, you can also hide the main form. Other possibilities include calling the Load-procedure from the modal progress dialog.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the `MainForm` as the `PopupParent` for the progress form so that the `MainForm` can never appear on top of the progress form.  Then simply set `MainForm.Enabled := False` while the progress form is open and set `MainForm.Enabled := True` when the progress form is closed.

```
procedure TMainForm.ShowProgressForm;
begin
  with TProgressForm.Create(nil) do
  begin
    PopupParent := Self;
    OnClose := ProgressFormClose;
    Show;
  end;
  Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TMainForm.ProgressFormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
  Enabled := True;
end;
```

This simulates how`ShowModal()` behaves to the user (the `MainForm` is not user-interactive while the progress form is open), but without blocking the code.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the direct answer to your question.

> I need to get the way, to disable everything on main form.

Set `MainForm.Enabled` to `False` to disable the window associated with the main form. And to re-enable set it to `True` instead.

---

Your fundamental problem however, is that you are executing long running tasks in the GUI thread. That's always a bad idea and the way out is to execute those long running tasks in a separate thread.

Once you move the long running tasks to a separate thread then you will find that `ShowModal` is exactly what you need to show your progress form.

Answer (score 2):

As I explained in my other answer, putting the long running task into a thread other than the GUI thread is the ideal solution. The GUI thread should handle short running tasks so that it is always able to service the message queue in a timely fashion.

However, if you already have code that assumes that the long running task runs on the GUI thread, you may prefer to take a more expedient approach and postpone the re-factoring to threaded code. In which case, in my view, it is still better to use `ShowModal` to display your progress form.

But in order to make that work, you need to find a let the long running task execute inside the `ShowModal` call. You can do that as follows:

1. Before you call `ShowModal`, pass the task to the form. For example, pass a `TProc` to the constructor of the progress form.
2. Override the progress form's `Activate` method. This will get executed just before the `ShowModal` function starts its modal message loop. In the implementation of `Activate`, post a message to the form.
3. When the form handles that message, invoke the task that was passed to the constructor.

Obviously you'll need to call `ProcessMessages` in your long running task, in order to keep the main GUI thread message queue serviced. Clearly you must already be doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Set the PopupParent of child form = ParentForm

```
procedure TParentForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ParentForm.Enabled:=False;
with Tform1.create(nil) do show;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
ParentForm.Enabled := true;
form1.free;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use  `DisableTaskWindows` and `EnableTaskWindows` functions.

If you use simple `ParentForm.Enabled := False` for the parent form, you can still access all other forms, like the main form if it differs from `ParentForm`. It is obviously still dangerous.

Here is short sample:

```
interface

uses
  Vcl.Forms, Winapi.Windows, ...;

type
  TPleaseWait = class(TObject)
  private
    fWindowList: TTaskWindowList;
    fActiveWindow: HWND;
    fDialog: TPleaseWaitForm;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TPleaseWait.Create;
begin
  // Disable all displayed windows
  fWindowList := DisableTaskWindows(0);

  // Save the last active window
  fActiveWindow := GetActiveWindow;

  fDialog := TPleaseWaitForm.Create(nil);
  fDialog.Show;
end;

destructor TPleaseWait.Destroy;
const
  INVALID_HANDLE = 0;
begin
  fDialog.Close;
  fDialog.Free;

  // All windows are enabled now
  EnableTaskWindows(fWindowList);

  // That helps by enabling the last one form
  if (fActiveWindow <> INVALID_HANDLE) and IsWindow(fActiveWindow) then
    SetActiveWindow(fActiveWindow);
  inherited;
end;

end.
```